# Move lines in file using awk/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hi my files look like:

```
>ID.1
GGAACACGACATCCTGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAAAAGTACTGGA
>ID.2
GGAATACCACATCCCGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAACAGTACTGGA
```

and I want to move the lines so that line 1 swaps with 3, and line 2 swaps with 4.

```
>ID.2
GGAATACCACATCCCGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAACAGTACTGGA
>ID.1
GGAACACGACATCCTGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAAAAGTACTGGA
```

I have thought about using `cut` so cut send the lines into other files, and then bring them all back in the desired order using `paste`, but is there a solution using awk/sed.

EDIT: The file always has 4 lines (2 fasta entrys), no more.

Comment: and what if a file contains 5 or 6 lines?

Comment: I don't see how `cut` could be of help here, so if you can think of a `cut`/`paste` solution, I would be curious to know it. If i would have to implement it, I would first create an array of all the lines in the file, and then write the new file based on a different order of the elements.

Comment: I also can't imagine how you think `cut` and `paste` would help you with this but you could do it with `awk` or `sed` but also man `head` and `tail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed '1h;2H;1,2d;4G'
```

- Store the first line in the hold space;
- Add the second line to the hold space;
- Don't print the first two lines;
- Before printing the fourth line, append the hold space to it (i.e. append the 1st and 2nd line).

Comment: Perhaps `sed '1h;2H;1,2d;4G' file`?

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple case, as @Ed_Morton mentioned, you can just swap the even-sized slices with `head` and `tail` commands:

```
$ tail -2 test.txt; head -2 test.txt
```

---

```
>ID.2
GGAATACCACATCCCGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAACAGTACTGGA
>ID.1
GGAACACGACATCCTGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAAAAGTACTGGA
```

Answer (score 2):

Generic solution with `GNU tac` to reverse contents:

```bash
$ tac -bs'>' ip.txt
>ID.2
GGAATACCACATCCCGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAACAGTACTGGA
>ID.1
GGAACACGACATCCTGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAAAAGTACTGGA
```

By default `tac` reverses line wise but you can customize the separator.

Here, I'm assuming `>` can be safely used as a unique separator (provided to the `-s` option). The `-b` option is used to put the separator before the content in the output.

---

Using `ed` (inplace editing):

```bash
# move 3rd to 4th lines to the top
printf '3,4m0\nwq\n' | ed -s ip.txt

# move the last two lines to the top
printf -- '-1,$m0\nwq\n' | ed -s ip.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU `AWK` manual has example of swapping two lines using [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable.html) as you know that

> The file always has 4 lines (2 fasta entrys), no more.

then you might care only about case when number of lines is evenly divisble by 4 and use `getline` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
>ID.1
GGAACACGACATCCTGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAAAAGTACTGGA
>ID.2
GGAATACCACATCCCGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAACAGTACTGGA
```

then

```
awk '{line1=$0;getline line2;getline line3;getline line4;printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",line3,line4,line1,line2}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
>ID.2
GGAATACCACATCCCGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAACAGTACTGGA
>ID.1
GGAACACGACATCCTGCAGGGTTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAAAAGTACTGGA
```

Explanation: store current line in variable `$0`, then next line as `line2`, yet next line as `line3`, yet next line as `line4`, use `printf` with 4 placeholders (`%s`) followed by newlines (`\n`), which are filled accordingly to your requirement.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed:

```
sed -zE 's/(.*\r?\n)(.*\r?\n?)/\2\1/' file
```

A Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(.*\R.*\R)(.*\R.*\R?)/\2\1/' file
```

A ruby:

```
ruby -ne 'BEGIN{lines=[]}
lines<<$_
END{puts lines[2...4]+lines[0...2] }' file
```

Paste and awk:

```
paste -s file | awk -F'\t' '{print $3, $4, $1, $2}' OFS='\n'
```

A POSIX pipe:

```
paste -sd'\t\n' file | nl | sort -nr | cut -f 2- | tr '\t' '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
awk -F'\n' '{print $3, $4, $1, $2}' OFS='\n' RS= ORS='\n\n' file.txt
```

Comment: That would add an extra blank line to the end of the output.